# Screen shifts a bit when change focus to next edittext

Tags: android

I have a little issue with the keyboard on my numberpicker.
It's kinda hard to explain in words so here are some screenshots:

When I click on the numberpicker the keyboard shows up:

[image]

When I click on the next button (in this case the 'Volg' button) I implemented that it should focus the next edittext.

[image]

But as you can see, the screen shifts a little to the top.
This is not a huge problem but it's kinda annoying.

What can cause this, or how can I fix this ?

Edit: the layout is a scrollview.

Comment: Can you paste your code?

Comment: Please add the layout xml or the code you are using to create the view

Answer (score 0):

try this

In your manifest file under activity tag use attribute

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged"

Comment: Maybe android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" would do the trick:)