# Keyboard covers up part of edittext

Tags: android

I have a numberpicker but my keyboard is not showing up like I want.

Screen:

[image]

As you can see, the keyboard covers part of the edittext.

How can I fix this **without using a scrollview**?

I've already tried setting android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" or "adjustResize".

When I use scrollview I get the following problem : 
[Screen shifts a bit when change focus to next edittext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12669308/screen-shifts-a-bit-when-change-focus-to-next-edittext)

Thx :)

Comment: you have a back button, srsly?

Comment: I know it's redundant and not good practice, but it's unfortunately not my choice :)

Comment: Why didn't adjustPan work? I just ran into this problem myself and that worked for me. I'm curious if you found a better way...

Answer (score -1):

in manifest file set activity attribute

`android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"`

like :

```
<activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden" >
```

it should work

Comment: Nope, didn't make a difference :(